# Java: cannot access a protected member of the superclass in the extending subclass

Tags: java, protected

I want some discussions about this, but I could not infer the answer for my case. Still need help.

Here is my code:

```
package JustRandomPackage;

public class YetAnotherClass{
    protected int variable = 5;
}
```

```
package FirstChapter;

import JustRandomPackage.*;

public class ATypeNameProgram extends YetAnotherClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        YetAnotherClass bill = new YetAnotherClass();
        System.out.println(bill.variable); // error: YetAnotherClass.variable is not visible

    }
}
```

Some definitions following which, the example above seems to be confusing:

```
 1. Subclass is a class that extends another class.
 2. Class members declared as protected can be accessed from 
    the classes in the same package as well as classes in other packages 
    that are subclasses of the declaring class.
```

**The question:** Why can't I access the protected member (`int variable = 5`) from a subclass `YetAnotherClass` instance (`bill` object)?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes in other packages that are subclasses of the declaring class can only access their own inherited `protected` members.

```
package FirstChapter;

import JustRandomPackage.*;

public class ATypeNameProgram extends YetAnotherClass{
    public ATypeNameProgram() {
        System.out.println(this.variable); // this.variable is visible
    }
}
```

... but not other objects' inherited `protected` members.

```
package FirstChapter;

import JustRandomPackage.*;

public class ATypeNameProgram extends YetAnotherClass{
    public ATypeNameProgram() {
        System.out.println(this.variable); // this.variable is visible
    }

    public boolean equals(ATypeNameProgram other) {
        return this.variable == other.variable; // error: YetAnotherClass.variable is not visible
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. This code compiles. A class in another package can only access inherited protected members that are of the same type as the class itself.

Comment: The type of the constructor argument  should be changed here, from ATypeNameProgram to YetAnotherClass , for the explanation to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

bill is not part of the subclassed YetAnotherClass. bill is a separate YetAnotherClass.

Try `int bill = this.variable;` (inside a constructor) to access the subclass' members.

Comment: Exactly! Well caught @mcalex.  He is making an object of the Super class, and not the Sub-class... Obviously there is a problem with my protected variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work if `YetAnotherClass` will be in the same package as `ATypeNameProgram`. As others wrote it won't work in other cases. Here is the working example.

```
package my.example;

public class MainClass extends MyAnotherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAnotherClass bill = new MyAnotherClass();
        System.out.println(bill.value); // this will work
    }
}

package my.example;

public class MyAnotherClass {

    protected int value = 5;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A class `Foo` can only access the protected instance members of type `Bar` if and only if `Bar` is assignable to `Foo`. I.e., if we can write:

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
```

For example, say we have:

```
package a;

public class Base {
    protected int protectedField;
}
```

Then we can have this:

```
package b;

import a.Base;

public class Parent extends Base {
    void foo() {
        int i = this.protectedField;
    }
    void foo(Parent p) {
        int i = p.protectedField;
    }
    void foo(Child c) {
        int i = c.protectedField;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent { }
```

This will compile because all `protectedField`s are accessed via instances of `Parent`. Note that because a `Parent` reference can be a `Child` instance (i.e., we can write `Parent p = new Child();`), we can access `c.protectedField`.

The following will *not* compile:

```
package b;

import a.Base;

public class Parent extends Base {
    void foo(Stepchild sc) {
        int i = sc.protectedField; // ERROR
    }
}

class Stepchild extends Base {}
```

because an instance of `Stepchild` is not an instance of `Parent`.

Somewhat confusingly, this won't compile either:

```
package b;

import a.Base;

public class Parent extends Base {}

class Child extends Parent {
    void foo(Parent p) {
        p.protectedField; // ERROR
    }
}
```

this is because a `Parent` object isn't a superclass or superinterface of `Child`, and so `Child` can't access its protected members.

If you ever have trouble remembering, just think of whether or not the type can be written to a reference of the type of the class. E.g., we can write:

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

but cannot write

```
Child c = new Parent();     // ERROR
Parent p = new Stepchild(); // ERROR
```

so `Child` won't have access to `Parent`'s protected members, and `Parent` won't have access to `Stepchild`'s protected members.

A couple final points:

Remember that `protected` access allows visibility among the package. In my experience, people forget this.

Finally, `protected static` members are always visible among the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating an instance of the class that extend it, but of the parent class. Check the code below:

```
public class ATypeNameProgram extends YetAnotherClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        YetAnotherClass bill = new YetAnotherClass();
        System.out.println(bill.variable); // error: YetAnotherClass.variable is not visible

        ATypeNameProgram a = new ATypeNameProgram();
        System.out.println(a.variable); //this will work

    }
}
```